# iOS getting "Video encoding failed" error

Tags: ios, swift, tumblr

While posting a video to tumblr from the following Swift 2.1 code, I get a "Video encoding failed" error:

```
let videoData  =  NSData(contentsOfURL: self.videoURL!)!

let video = videoData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([]) 

 oauthswift. client.request ("http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/"+"\(userNameTmblr)"+".tumblr.com/post",  method: .POST, parameters: ["type":"video","caption":self.captionTextBox.text!,"data": video], headers: [:], checkTokenExpiration: true, success: { response in
  print("Successs...Post video Tumblr. ....") } }
```

Is this code doing anything wrong that could cause Tumblr to get this error?

Answer (score 0):

The Documention of Tumblr is Wrong.
documention says parameter as "data" But Actually there should be "data64".

Now it works perfectly